# ,Numpy how to extend strip numbers from certain position?

Tags: python, numpy

I want use python numpy to extend multiple number from certain point say the number "1" at [3,2].
suppose I key in "Right3" then, the right 3 element (couting from [3,2]) self plus 10. and if I key in "Left1" then, the rightest element become 20. hope you can understand me.
thank you

```py
[3, 2]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

expect to be:

```py
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 10. 10. 20. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: No, I don't understand. Can you create an example with less redundant zeroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean by key. You can check this out:

```
zero = np.zeros((8,12))
current_pos = (6, 2)

def right(steps, incr = 10):
    global zero, current_pos
    new_pos = (current_pos[0], current_pos[1] + steps)
    zero[current_pos[0],current_pos[1]+1 : new_pos[1]+1] += incr
    current_pos = new_pos

def left(steps, incr = 10):
    global zero, current_pos
    new_pos = (current_pos[0], current_pos[1] - steps)
    zero[current_pos[0],new_pos[1]+1 : current_pos[1]+1] += incr
    current_pos = new_pos

right(3)
print(zero)
left(1)
print(zero)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. 10. 10. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1. 10. 10. 20.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: awesome ! Thank you Sayandip, that's exact what I want !

Comment: Glad to help :)